# Arraylist into JList problems

Tags: java, arraylist, jlist

I have trouble putting my `arrayList` into a `Jlist`. 
This is what I have:

**Main Class:**

```
  package domain;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> purposeCategories = new ArrayList<String>();
    purposeCategories.add("Behavioral");
    purposeCategories.add("Structural");
    purposeCategories.add("Creational");
 }
```

I have put my list declaration in my `Jframe` class and I have the import domain.main; But it says that it doesn't recognize `purposeCategories`...What am I forgetting?

```
 JList list_purpose = new JList(purposeCategories.toArray());
    list_purpose.setBounds(50, 121, 121, 63);
    contentPane.add(list_purpose);
```

Also sorry for my English and thank you for your time:D

Comment: You should read a tutorial on the structure of classes in Java. You can't access a local variable from outside the method.

Comment: Please be more specific about the context of your second code fragment. Note that since `purposeCategories` is a local variable in your `main()` method, the `new JList(...)` fragment would also need to be in the same method, or have the value of that local variable passed to it. Explain exactly why you think the code as stated should work.

Comment: And you shouldn't be using null layouts....

Answer (score 0):

The list is in a different scope. Do this in your Jframe class:

```
public MyFrame(List<String> data) {
//now put your code for the Jlist   here using the variable name "data" for your list
}
```